# upload image by simpleimage.php

Tags: file-upload, image-uploading

i'm new in php and i'm trying to use Simpleimage.php but they ever print error of type error image.

Post code
          
           Immagine

```
      $image = new SimpleImage();
      $image->load('$_FILES[file][tmp_name]');
      $image->resize(250,400);
      $image->save('http://localhost:8080/GuitarShop/images/chitarre/ciao.jpg');
```

Where have i wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to put value of variable in load method, not name of variable, so try this:

```
$image->load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

and you should use ' in array index.

Turn on displaying errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and always try fix them.